# Add page tab app twice to the same facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have created a facebook page app that customers can install on their facebook page and it's add a tab on their page.

I want to add this app again (that mean that they will be able to add this app tab twice to the same page) and I didn't found any way to do this.

I have a link to install this app (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=XXX&next=XXX) on facebook pages but I don't see the pages that already installed this tab app).

How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the pages that have page tab already installed as one application can be added only once per page as a page tab. This is the restriction imposed by the Facebook. You can only have one app per tab per Facebook page.